# params set in grails filter are available in controller but missing in view

Tags: grails

i have a filter that sets params.freeWeeks.  In my controller when i println params i get

[action:blah, controller:home, freeWeeks:3]

if in my view i output via ${params} i get [action:blah, controller:home]

any idea why?  I can set request.freeWeeks in the filter and that makes it to the view.

I could add it to the template via the controller but i'd have to do it in every controller on the site and thats too many.

grails version = 1.3.1

---

more info - it turns out hat the issue only exposes itself if i'm inside a template (_someFile)

Comment: I use 1.3.6 and have the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like i'm hitting this bug http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6692

Comment: and here i thought the bug was fixed - it was just closed as a dupe - gah